# With {gtsummary}, how can I format data frames of pre-calculated summaries?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I have two similar data frames of summary statistics.

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)

stats_df <- tribble(
  ~name, ~est, ~ci.lwr, ~ci.upr,
  "bias", 1.2, 0.9, 1.5,
  "loa.upr", 4, 3.5, 4.5,
  "loa.lwr", -3, -3.5, -2.5
)
```

I want to display these in a {gtsummary} table.

The end goal is to compare two sets of summaries side-by-side. Similar to this, but without N, n(%) and p-values.
[image: example of goal]

My attempts with {gt} quickly gets very fiddly...

```
stats_df %>% 
  gt(rowname_col = "name") %>% 
  cols_merge_range(ci.lwr, ci.upr) %>% 
  cols_label(ci.lwr = "CI (95%)") %>% 
  tab_row_group("Limits of agreement", rows = starts_with("loa"))
```

[image: attempt]

Comment: Hello @JohannesNE ! Unfortunately, these type of pre-summarized/calculated data can't be incorporated into a gtsummary table.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply. I'll try to look through your source code for how you make gt behave as with gtsummary.